# Abstract class vs interface when sharing an attribute

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

I have a few classes which are the same "level" in a subtype hierarchy. I need to create an ID for each instance and I usually do this by having a parent class, containing a static long and I just increment it for every instance of the subclass.

75% of the code for the subtypes is the same- this made me prefer to use an abstract class (over an interface) as:

1) I can declare a static variable for the ID creator

2) I can put the code in the parent class and share it amongst the subtypes

Is this correct? I seem to rarely use interfaces. Should I only use interfaces when subtypes need the same methods, but different implementations and also when I do not need to initialize an attribute to be shared across the subtypes (like the ID creator)?

I had always been given the impression from colleagues that Interfaces were preferred to inheritance.

Comment: This sort of static state is probably a code smell by itself.  Can you maybe figure out a way to factor that out into a factory or something that provides the incrementing ID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have more than one group of classes that need ID generation, then I wouldn't advise using inheritance because it constrains reuse. In that case why not build a separate abstraction that provides the service of unique ID generation? You'd give it a key and it would give you an ID that is unique across all invocations using the same key.

```
public class IdGenerator 
{
  private IdGenerator() {} // no instantiation or subclassing
  private static final ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicLong> ids =
    new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicLong>();

  public static long id(String key) {
    AtomicLong al = ids.get(key);
    if (al == null) {
      final AtomicLong newL = new AtomicLong(0);
      al = ids.putIfAbsent(key, newL);
      if (al == null) al = newL;
    }
    return al.getAndIncrement();
  }
}
```

Comment: could you explain more please?

Comment: Are we talking delegation here?

Comment: @user997112 Not really since your classes wouldn't need to implement the unique ID interface. Do you need them to implement it?

Comment: @Marko, all I need is for each of my subtypes to have an ID, unique across all the subtypes. I presume the abstract class was ok for sharing the code though?

Comment: @user997112 It is ok to share code only used by the subclasses in question. You say you "usually do this", which sounds to me like you would have more than one such group of classes.

Comment: I have done this in the past, however, the problem was that I would have to create the IDGenerator object in the testing code and pass the instance into every constructor of my subtypes?

Comment: @user997112 Notice that the method is `static`. You just call it from anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

[Interfaces and abstract class](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2001-04/03-qa-0420-abstract.html) **serve different purpose**. An interface is generally used to specify a **contract** by which the users of the interface sees how to use it whereas an abstract class may be **partial implementation** of an interface.

Coming on to your question of attribute sharing, the variables declared in a interface are **static and more importantly final** and since you need an ID which you want it to be incremented, having that id will not work and so what you are having right now and working is fair approach.

Comment: It could work if he had `AtomicLong` in the interface. Not that I, or anyone else, would recommend such an approach.